# How can I save a matrix from one dataset to another?

Tags: matrix, stata

I have created a matrix `A` from `dataset1` and I want to use this later in `dataset2`.

How can I programmatically save this matrix and import it to `dataset2`?

Answer (score 1):

Consider the following toy datasets:

```
/* create dataset 1 */

clear
set obs 5

forvalues i = 1 / 5 {
    generate norm`i' = rnormal(10, 20)
}

list

     +----------------------------------------------------------+
     |    norm1       norm2       norm3       norm4       norm5 |
     |----------------------------------------------------------|
  1. |   29.184    47.57735    -6.06845    47.43953    12.10697 |
  2. |   9.9639    65.09492    31.92023    18.47133    39.01292 |
  3. | 20.88154   -2.251937    1.185946    22.67908   -11.98451 |
  4. | 10.03257    13.94616   -10.22853    18.34467    37.34412 |
  5. | 17.15362    42.20448    30.38455   -.5586708    20.34926 |
     +----------------------------------------------------------+

save data1, replace

/* create dataset 2 */

clear
set obs 5

forvalues i = 1 / 5 {
    generate unif`i' = runiform()
}

list

     +------------------------------------------------------+
     |    unif1      unif2      unif3      unif4      unif5 |
     |------------------------------------------------------|
  1. | .4398566    .222692    .359981   .8840723    .840627 |
  2. | .8955406   .7279246   .7385288   .1269085   .2610574 |
  3. | .6760237   .5028067   .9236897   .2413106   .8938763 |
  4. | .9666038   .0491344   .0098985   .4427792   .8565752 |
  5. | .4118744    .368421   .1528643   .8636661   .0944128 |
     +------------------------------------------------------+

save data2, replace
```

One can do this using the `svmat` command:

```
use data1, clear

mkmat norm*, matrix(A)

use data2, clear
matrix list A

A[5,5]
         norm1       norm2       norm3       norm4       norm5
r1      29.184   47.577354  -6.0684505   47.439529   12.106971
r2   9.9638996   65.094917   31.920233   18.471329    39.01292
r3    20.88154  -2.2519367   1.1859455   22.679077  -11.984506
r4   10.032575   13.946158  -10.228531   18.344669   37.344124
r5   17.153618   42.204475   30.384546  -.55867082   20.349257

svmat A, names(norm)
list

     +-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
     |    unif1      unif2      unif3      unif4      unif5      norm1       norm2       norm3       norm4       norm5 |
     |-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------|
  1. | .4398566    .222692    .359981   .8840723    .840627     29.184    47.57735    -6.06845    47.43953    12.10697 |
  2. | .8955406   .7279246   .7385288   .1269085   .2610574     9.9639    65.09492    31.92023    18.47133    39.01292 |
  3. | .6760237   .5028067   .9236897   .2413106   .8938763   20.88154   -2.251937    1.185946    22.67908   -11.98451 |
  4. | .9666038   .0491344   .0098985   .4427792   .8565752   10.03257    13.94616   -10.22853    18.34467    37.34412 |
  5. | .4118744    .368421   .1528643   .8636661   .0944128   17.15362    42.20448    30.38455   -.5586708    20.34926 |
     +-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
```

Note that this solution will work if the `clear matrix` and/or `clear all` have not been invoked.